# How to redirect camera to Windows Server VM RDP?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have windows server VM, I have to use my laptop webcam and Microphone from VM.
I have tried many things like redirection local resources and redirect policy from gpupdate but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mstsc.exe`, have you tried this:
[image]
`Local Resources` > `Local devices and resources` > `More...` > `Video capture devices` and `Integrated Camera`

Comment: I had tried same thing but didn't work.